# $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }\left ( 2\log n-\frac{n}{\log n} \right )$

Tags: limits

How to caculate $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }\left ( 2\log n-\frac{n}{\log n} \right )$$
Thanks for helping.

Comment: L'Hopital solves almost all such limits. Why don't you use it?

Comment: @Crostul, to be fair the OP might not know how to get the limit into a form, suitable for L'Hospital. I you do, then consider giving a hint

Comment: The easiest way here is to use knowledge that the growth rate of $log(n)$ is lower than growth rate of $n^a$ for arbitrary $a>0$

Answer (score 2):

It is known that the functions $\;\{n^a\log^bn\mid (a,b)\in \mathbf R^2\}\;$ constitute an *asymptotic scale*, i.e. these functions are totally ordered by the lexicographic order on the set $\;\bigl\{(a,b)\in \mathbf R^2\bigr\}$:
$$n^a\log^bn=o\bigl(n^{a'}\log^{b'}n\bigr)\iff a<a'\enspace\text{or}\enspace (a=a',\:b<b').$$
Thus $\;\log n=o\Bigl(\dfrac n{\log n}\Bigr)$, whence$\;2\log n-\dfrac{n}{\log n}\sim_\infty -\dfrac{n}{\log n}$ tends to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not hard to show that for large $n$ we have
$$
\log n < \frac{\sqrt n}{2}
$$
Using this we can have the following upper bound
\begin{align*}
 2\log n-\frac{n}{\log n} &= \frac{2 \log^2 n -n}{\log n}\\ 
&\leq \frac{n/2 -n}{\log n} \\
& = \frac{-1}{2}\frac{n}{\log n} \\
& \leq \frac{-1}{2}\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}/2} \\
& \leq -\sqrt n \\
\end{align*}
which goes to negative infinity as $n$ gets larger.